# filter the same values in a row add the same values together

Tags: r

In the sample of the dataset below, from the icase_id column, I want to remove numbers that appear more than two (>2) and less than (<2) times.

icase_id 2,2,3,3,3,1,4,4

summ
2
3
1
2
3
4
2
1

2. after doing that, want to count the total of each set of numbers and save it in one single icase_id, example as this:

icase_id 2, 4

summ      5, 3

so i need someones help how to accomplished this exercise. Thanking in advance

Comment: So, would you say you want to keep only the values that occur exactly 3 times? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: yeah in the icase_id column, i want to keep only values that occure 3x. less than or more than 3x will be removed. then in the second point, sum the values using one specific number identity as shown in figure 2. i tried mRS_score %>% dplyr::filter(icase_id %in% ==3) but that gives me different output compare to what am asking

Comment: `icase_id %in% 3` would only keep `icase_id` if its value is 3. You need to count each case id. Look up `group_by` and `n()`. .Reading [An introduction to `dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) would be a good place to start - it covers this stuff well.

Comment: Pls post data no pictures

Comment: i want to do that i was not able to post data thats why.. sorry for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty basic stuff with `library(dplyr)`

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(icase_id=c(2,2,3,3,3,1,4,4),summ=c(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1))

df %>% 
  group_by(icase_id) %>%
  filter(n()==2 ) %>% 
  summarise(summ=sum(summ))
```

Comment: that was magnificent.. in case it was three columns, and i want to apply the above code to all  of the dataset where will i place the square bracket and comma?